# List items showing random color in css

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

total noob here trying to build a website for a college assignment.
I have it looking the way I want except for the navigation menu.
I wanted to set the links to be a certain color, then change the color for 'hover', change it again for 'active' and again for 'visited'. The 'hover' and 'active' commands work great, but if I activate the 'visited' command it seems to just make the links that color, and commenting it out turns the links a purple color that I didn't even specify anywhere. I have no clue how this is even possible.
HTML:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>home</title>
    <style> 
    </style>
    <link href="style/homeContent.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body 
{
    background-color: #1B1716;
}

.nav
{
    font-family: source-sans-pro;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
} 
.nav li
{
    display: inline;
}
.nav a
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 100px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.nav a:link
{
    color: #E4E4E4;
}
.nav a:hover
{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #FFFFFF;
}
.nav a:visited
{
    color: #CDCDCD;
}
.nav a:active
{
    color: #C60003;
}
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: I can't really see you problem, what style do you want for the `:visited` version of the link?
Also, the purple text is browser default

Comment: thanks for answering Isigiel, I did not know that purple is a browser default. I presume it is across the board because it's happening with chrome, safari and firefox. If so this means my .nav a:link {color: #E4E4E4;} is being completely ignored. The :visited should only happen after the link has been clicked.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your code is completely correct, run the snippet I made, where I changed up the colors so you can see which lines are applied, links are blue now, then turn whitewhen you hover, red when you click and green after being clicked.

The purple you mentioned is a browser default, that just get's applied to all visited links.

```css
body 
{
    background-color: #1B1716;
}

.nav
{
    font-family: source-sans-pro;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
} 
.nav li
{
    display: inline;
}
.nav a
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 100px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.nav a:link
{
    color: green;
}
.nav a:hover
{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #FFFFFF;
}
.nav a:visited
{
    color: blue;
}
.nav a:active
{
    color: #C60003;
}
```

```html
   <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>home</title>
    <style> 
    </style>
    <link href="style/homeContent.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you again Isigiel, your code works phenomenally. I think I have figured out what is going on though: basically, once you click the links, the a:visited part takes over indefinitely, even if you refresh the page. But if I quit the browser and restart the whole thing the link colour goes back to default... until you click on it. This happens with your code too. I can work with this for now, it is not high priority anyway. thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Visited links are based on your browser history, so they could show up differently for everyone. Some browsers will reset this every time you close them and some of them will keep them "visited" until you clear your history.